# How do I populate File Names and Date Modified of multiple files from a Folder in a multi column ListBox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of files in my folder. 
I need a 2-column listbox.

The first column should show the list of File Names in the folder.

The second column should show the corresponding Data Modified of these File Names.

This is the code that is populating the File Names for me correctly:

```
'CLEAR LISTBOX
ListBox1.Clear

'BUILD A LIST OF ALL FILES
FileName = Dir(FilePath & "*" & "*")
While FileName <> ""


'ADD FILE NAMES TO THE LIST
I = I + 1
ReDim Preserve FileList(1 To I)
FileList(I) = FileName


'GET NEXT FILENAMES
FileName = Dir()
Wend


'WERE ANY FILES FOUND
If I = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files found!"
Exit Sub
End If


'CYCLE THROUGH LIST AND ADD TO LISTBOX
For I = 1 To UBound(FileList)
Me.ListBox1.AddItem FileList(I)
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the FileSystemObject as you can access that property directly. You can also get a count of the number of files, so you can dimension your array before populating it.

I wrote the below code using early-binding for Microsoft Scripting Runtime, but you can certainly use late-binding if necessary.

```
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FO As Folder, FI As File, FIs As Files

    'Don't forget to declare FilePath as in your code

    Dim FileList()
    Dim I As Long

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(FilePath)
Set FIs = FO.Files

ReDim FileList(1 To FIs.Count, 1 To 2)
I = 0

'Populate the FileList array
For Each FI In FIs
    I = I + 1
    FileList(I, 1) = FI.Name
    FileList(I, 2) = FI.DateLastModified
Next FI

'Clear the ListBox
'Then declare the number of columns and populate it
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .List = FileList
End With
```